# JavaScript script doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox, dom-events

I have an old function which is missing lines for Mozilla/Firefox and thus JavaScript is not working properly in it. The function tracks mouse-coordinates, so that I can position windows.

How to make the code work in Firefox as well?

```
Xoffset = -60; // modify these values to ...
Yoffset = 20; // change the popup position.
var old, skn, iex = (document.all),
    yyy = -1000;

var ns4 = document.layers
var ns6 = document.getElementById && !document.all
var ie4 = document.all

if (ns4) skn = document.dek
else if (ns6) skn = document.getElementById("dek").style
else if (ie4) skn = document.all.dek.style
if (ns4) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
else {
  skn.visibility = "visible"
  skn.display = "none"
}
document.onmousemove = get_mouse;


function popup(msg, bak) {
  var content = 
      "<TABLE  WIDTH=150 BORDER=1 BORDERCOLOR=black CELLPADDING=2" +
      "CELLSPACING=0 " + "BGCOLOR=" + bak + "><TD ALIGN=center>" + 
      "<FONT COLOR=black SIZE=2>" + msg + "</FONT></TD></TABLE>";
  yyy = Yoffset;
  if (ns4) {
    skn.document.write(content);
    skn.document.close();
    skn.visibility = "visible"
  }
  if (ns6) {
    document.getElementById("dek").innerHTML = content;
    skn.display = ''
  }
  if (ie4) {
    document.all("dek").innerHTML = content;
    skn.display = ''
  }
}

function get_mouse(e) {
  var x = (ns4 || ns6) ? event.pageX : event.x + document.body.scrollLeft;
  skn.left = x + Xoffset;
  var y = (ns4 || ns6) ? event.pageY : event.y + document.body.scrollTop;
  if (document.documentElement &&  // IE6 +4.01 but no scrolling going on
     !document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
    y = event.y + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
  else if (document.documentElement && // IE6 +4.01 and user has scrolled
           document.documentElement.scrollTop) { 
    y = event.y + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
  else if (document.body && document.body.scrollTop) { // IE5 or DTD 3.2
    y = event.y + document.document.body.scrollTop;
  }

  skn.top = y + yyy;
}

function kill() {
  yyy = -1000;
  if (ns4) {
    skn.visibility = "hidden";
  }
  else if (ns6 || ie4) skn.display = "none"
}
```

I am getting this error:

> **"event is not defined"**

Works ok in IE.

Comment: Seriously, use jQuery. It abstracts away all this nonsense about different browser interfaces into something sensible.

Comment: Looks like you defined `event` variable as `e` in `get_mouse` method signature.

Comment: +1 for jQuery. Besides that NS is dead. Especially NS4...

Comment: This should help you out: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#mousepos

Comment: The problem is your conditional. You seem to be testing for ns4 or ns6, and if that evaluates to false, it will try to calculate event.x. Firefox will not qualify in ns4 or ns6, and it does not support event.x either. You need to add a firefox test to your (ns4 || ns6) conditional, because it also uses e.pageX

Comment: I've added complete code. Suggestions are good but still can;t make it work. This code basically adds hover effects boxes to lots of links.

Comment: @RussellUresti Can you help me with conditional?

Comment: This is like the worst looking code I've seen in this year. :)

Comment: @galambalazs Everybody seems to criticize the code but nobody comes up with a solution. This awful looking code sniplet works on all browsers but FF because of the conditional and a incompatible clause.

Comment: @Codex73 Instead of testing for browsers, I would test to see if the object / property exist. For example: "var x = e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;" - I think there may be an easier way to do this, such as "var x = e.pageX || e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;" but I'm not sure that will work. Test it out and see what you get. Also, for more detail, review: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Comment: @RussellUresti Can you please answer question with comment you made? I believe this is my best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of testing for browsers, I would test to see if the object / property exists. For example:

```
var x = e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
```

I think there may be an easier way to do this, such as

```
var x = e.pageX || e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
```

but I'm not sure that will work. Test it out and see what you get. Also, for more detail, review: [quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

Also note that I changed "event" to "e", since the parameter you're passing into the function is "e". If you want to still use event, rewrite the parameter to:

```
function get_mouse(event)
```

While I don't believe "event" is a reserved word for JS, a lot of browsers use it, so I would suggest sticking to "e".

Answer (score 7):

I'm not going to post code on how to rewrite your code @Ivo Wetzel's is pretty much what you need, but let meg give you some advice.

1. The world is changing fast, so does the computer industry. And while sometimes it's not as fast as we want (IE 6 fading slowly) there is no need to support Netscape 4.
2. Consult with a site like **[StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com)** to find out what browsers are in use (in your country/region). Also consult with **[YUI graded browser support](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/)**. Yahoo is one of the biggest players on the internet, their site has to work for almost everyone, so they know what they're talking about.
3. Find a good DOM reference. **[MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom)** is pretty much what you need, but it's good to have **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)** for IE quirks. Talking about quirks, don't forget to bookmark **[QuirksMode compatibility tables](http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)**.
4. Never use things like `ie4 = document.all`, because a single feature won't identify a whole browser. It's like saying: *"Hey you've got blonde hair, you must be Brad Pitt"*. Use feature detection. Read these two excellent articles: **[Browser Detection (and What to Do Instead)](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/)** and **[Feature Detection: State of the Art Browser Scripting](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting)**
5. Don't use `document.write` because it's synchronous I/O which is awful. It blocks your page rendering and leads to bad user experience. The Web is all about being **[asynchronous](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/04/synchronous-v-asynchronous/)**.

> *"Synchronous programming is disrespectful and should not be employed in applications which are used by people."  - Douglas Crockford*

Comment: Very good, concise and to the point. I apreciate the honest answer and direction. Great remarks! At least I didn't write this code!! Thanks again @galambalazs

Answer (score 3):

Oh my god... this must be the worst code I've seen in years, well let's try to clean it up then:

```
Xoffset = -60; // modify these values to ...
Yoffset = 20; // change the popup position.
var old, skn = document.getElementById("dek").style, yyy = -1000;

function popup(msg, bak) {
    var content = 
        "<TABLE  WIDTH=150 BORDER=1 BORDERCOLOR=black CELLPADDING=2" +
        "CELLSPACING=0 " + "BGCOLOR=" + bak + "><TD ALIGN=center>" + 
        "<FONT COLOR=black SIZE=2>" + msg + "</FONT></TD></TABLE>";

    yyy = Yoffset;
    document.getElementById("dek").innerHTML = content;
    skn.display = '';
}

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    var x = e.pageX !== undefined ? e.pageX : e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    var y = e.pageY !== undefined ? e.pageY : e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    skn.left = x + Xoffset;
    skn.top = y + yyy;
}

function kill() {
  yyy = -1000;
  skn.display = "none";
}
```

It's still broken beyond repair, but it *should* work... somehow.... Well, unless you post the rest of them HTML there's no way I can test this.

Please, I beg you... get rid of all that crap and use jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to change all your instances of 'event' to 'e'.

Comment: Not exactly right, the "event" is only being called because his conditional is incorrect. Firefox wouldn't support the "e.x" being assigned through the ternary. He needs to add a test for firefox in his (ns4 || ns6) conditional. Which makes me think this code is old... should probably just be redone from scratch at this point.

Comment: Yeah it was just a first suggestion because there's no declaration of event, only e from the function.  It needs more work than that to get it working in FF.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox includes `document.documentElement` and `document.documentElement.scrollTop` and `document.body` and `document.body.scrollTop` so you're entering regions that were meant for IE with Firefox.

You should also start your function with something like

```
function get_mouse(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
```

Then use `e` instead of `event` in all the places you use `event`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `var event = e` on the first line of function body, if you are afraid of hassles
`function get_mouse(e) { var event = e;`